# objecj.inner == "xx" check failed while running a script in console

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web-scraping, automation

Hello guys I was trying to automate the "buy now" option for an E-commerce site through the Console (inspect->console) in Chrome browser, but only the "else loop" is being executed, though the "if condtion" is true, in my case I took a product in flipkart.com and tried this script it keeps running the else loop can anyone say why is it so. i even tried changing the condition for "if" to check =="BUY NOW" yet still nothing seems to work

```js
var time = setInterval(function() {

  var a = document.getElementsByClassName('_2AkmmA')[0].innerHTML;
  if (a == "Buy Now") {
    document.getElementsByClassName('_2AkmmA')[0].click();
    clearInterval(time);
  } else {
    console.log("Script Activated");
  }
  
}, 10);
```

```html
<button class="_2AkmmA">Buy Now</div>
```

Comment: so debug and find out `console.log(escape(a), '== "Buy Now"');`

Comment: make sure the value of the 'a' first. May be there is a space at the end of the string

Comment: @SajithaRathnayake hello sir, I have already checked the HTML script for the same and there was no any extra space

Comment: @epascarello I couldn't understand how does the escape(a) can be useful for debugging  I am a beginner with javascript so brief your solution

Comment: It is not a solution, escape or encodeURIComponent can be used to show hidden characters in a string that you might miss when just looking at it. My guess is your string that is being returned back has extra stuff in it. AKA whitespace, new lines, etc. Did you add the console line and see what it returns?

Comment: most probably there will be a \r or \n (New line)end of the string

Comment: @epascarello for the same what you have stated iam getting an output like this: "Script Activated
VM433:3 %3Csvg%20class%3D%22_3oJBMI%22%20width%3D%2216%22%20height%3D%2216%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2016%2015%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%3E%3Cpath%20class%3D%22%22%20d%3D%22M15.32%202.405H4…l%3D%22%23fff%22%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E%20%3C%21--%20--%3EADD%20TO%20CART == "Buy Now"
"   discard that initial thing script activated

Comment: @SajithaRathnayake please take a look at these console outputs, I found that Its not working even by just providing object.click : document.getElementsByClassName('_2AkmmA _2Npkh4 _2kuvG8 _7UHT_c')[0].click
ƒ click() { [native code] }
document.getElementsByClassName('_2AkmmA _2Npkh4 _2kuvG8 _7UHT_c')[0].innerText
" BUY NOW" .. I even noticed that they are in caps and extra space in beginning I even changed it though it's not working. for any website, this command (document.getElementsByClassName('respective class name')[0].click;
ƒ click() { [native code] })does not work